# Call the function only after the browser is fully redirected?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

```
<script>
function test() {
    alert("this should only be called after the browser is fully redirected?");
}
window.location = "http://google.com";
test();
</script>
```

I'm about redirecting the user guys to a page and I want to do something (call a function) only after the browser is fully redirected but I can't get it to work. Is there any way for me to do so?

Comment: i don't believe this would work. it's a form of XSS/injection and therefore a security risk. i don't think the W3C allowed this sort of thing because it's very dangerous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way for me to do so?

Nope. When the page has opened `google.com`, you no longer have any control over the browser window.

Comment: @tekkno I don't see that much background to add here to be honest - this is not so much a Single Origin Policy issue than it is a memory issue: When one document is loaded, the old one is completely "forgotten".

Comment: Thanks but if I'm in http://mydomain.site/user.php?for=example and I redirect to http://mydomain.site/ , will I be able to do it?

Comment: @user if you have control over the target page, why not add `test()` to the target document's `load` event?

Comment: @Pekka -> it's also Same Origin policy, and not allowed for a reason. memory (on all new computers) really is not an issue

Comment: @tekkno you don't understand what I mean. There can be no interaction between page A and page B in the first place, because they are completely separate entities in the browser's memory. Security concerns never apply.

Comment: Though it is related to javascript, say, accessing tabs, closing other windows, it just *is not allowed*. I do get it.

Answer (score 2):

Once URL changes, all execution of the current page is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You'd have to put the page you were redirecting in a frame and keep the script in another frame, then watch for the content frame to get updated. But you'd also run into cross-domain issues because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (which governs access to one document's contents [the new page] from another document [the one containing the script you're running]). So basically, you can't do this.

If you post a separate question saying what you're trying to achieve by running more code afterward, it may be that people can help you with alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe this would work. it's a form of XSS/injection and therefore a security risk. i don't think the W3C allowed this sort of thing because it's very dangerous. as soon as the user is loading a different page, the browser ignores the previous one.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/439675/HTML-JavaScript/Javascript-call-AFTER-redirect

see that guy's answer for a visual